# HashMap containsKey method

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I'm writing an implementation of HashMap in java and I'm running into some issues with locating the correct bucket in the containsKey method

```
public class MyHashMap<K, V> {

LinkedList<MyEntry>[] table;
int size;
float maxLoadFactor;

public boolean containsKey(K key) {

    if(this.isEmpty())
        return false;
    if(table[table.length % key.hashCode()].isEmpty())
        return false;
    else {
    for(int i = 0; i < table[table.length % key.hashCode()].size(); i++) { 
        if(table[table.length % key.hashCode()].get(i).key == key)
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm running into issues mainly with table[table.length % key.hashCode()].  I don't think this is the right way to go about locating the correct bucket for the hash table, but I'm not sure what is.  Any help is appreciated.  If you have any questions please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific as to the issues you're running into.  Is your code crashing?  If so, with what exception?  If not, can you give some sample calling code and what it outputs, versus what you would expect it to output.  There's too little information as it stands to answer this.

Comment: First thing to do is to pull `table.length % key.hashCode()` out of the for loop and assign it to a temp, so you can easily dump it and so that the code is more legible.

Comment: LinkedList isn't a very good choice for your base table -- it'll probably work but performance will suck.  And you've got your `%` expression backwards.  Look up how `%` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

In each place you're using `table.length % key.hashCode()`, it should be `key.hashCode() % table.length`. This means if the hashCode is greater than the size of the table, it will 'wrap around' to the beginning. Or rather, it computes the remainder of key.hashCode()/table.length and puts it there. Hope that helps!

Comment: +1, but it's important to note that this expression will have to match the corresponding expressions in `get()` and `put()`. It's probably best to factor it out into its own private method, something like `getBucket()`.